# Uri with empty Path

Tags: c#, .net, uri

Is is possible to represent a URL with an empty path component with System.Uri?

Whenever I create

```
new Uri("http://example.com")
```

.Net (4) seems to insist on appending a trailing slash, thereby creating a different URL. In other words,

```
new Uri("http://example.com").ToString()
```

returns "http://example.com/" and

```
new Uri("http://example.com").Equals(new Uri("http://example.com/")) == true
```

Can this broken behavior (according to RFC 3986) be suppressed or do I have to roll my own class?

**Update:**

Looks like I missed this in section 6.2.3:

> In general, a URI that uses the generic syntax for authority with an
>   empty path should be normalized to a path of "/".

The wording indicates this is optional however. So the question remains: can Uri be made to NOT do this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_normalization "For http and https URLs, the following normalizations listed in RFC 3986 may result in equivalent URLs, but are not guaranteed to by the standards:
**Adding trailing /** Directories are indicated with a trailing slash and should be included in URLs"

Comment: @TimSchmelter Right, so .Net is applying a "Normalization[s] that usually preserve semantics". Which means it is not always correct, and in my case it is dead wrong.

The question is: can it be disabled?

Comment: @arbitrix Can you explain why does it matter to you? Why is it “dead wrong”?

Comment: @svick Because in this particular use case the server treats a bare hostname (200 OK) different from one with a trailing slash appended (404 Not Found and/or 301 Permanent Redirect). Which means the normalization does not preserve semantics. Note that I have no control over this and I'm not trying to start a discussion on whether this is desirable or not.

Comment: @arbitrix I'm confused. When you make a HTTP request to URI like `http://example.com/index.html`, then the request actually contains `GET /index.htm`. So, `http://example.com/` becomes `GET /`, but I have no idea what `http://example.com` should be (if it has to be different).

Comment: @arbitrix Also, according to the [HTTP 1.1 RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.2): “Note that the absolute path cannot be empty; if none is present in the original URI, it MUST be given as "/".”

Comment: Are you sure you have to swim upstream on this?  Is it possible/better to go with the flow and treat them the same, like 99% of servers do?  I realise it means changing something else.

Comment: @svick You are right. Which would mean that the answer to my question is "no". Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET 2.0 you can get the original string passed to the constructor via [`OriginalString` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.originalstring.aspx). The original string is lost when `Uri` object is serialized.

If this is not what you want, there is no help. `Equals` and `ToString` methods will always use the normalized version.