# How to try create an url from an uri without a trailing `/`?

Tags: c#, uri

If I run this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
public static void Main()
{
    Uri.TryCreate("https://dotnetfiddle.net", UriKind.Absolute, out var result);
    Console.WriteLine(result); // should be "https://dotnetfiddle.net"

    Uri.TryCreate("https://dotnetfiddle.net:5555", UriKind.Absolute, out var result5555);
    Console.WriteLine(result5555); // should be "https://dotnetfiddle.net:5555"

    Uri.TryCreate("https://dotnetfiddle.net?a=1", UriKind.Absolute, out var result2);
    Console.WriteLine(result2); // should be "https://dotnetfiddle.net?a=1"

    Uri.TryCreate("https://dotnetfiddle.net/", UriKind.Absolute, out var result3);
    Console.WriteLine(result3); // correct

    Uri.TryCreate("https://dotnetfiddle.net/?a=1", UriKind.Absolute, out var result4);
    Console.WriteLine(result4); // correct

    Uri.TryCreate("https://dotnetfiddle.net/test", UriKind.Absolute, out var result5);
    Console.WriteLine(result5); ; // correct

    Uri.TryCreate("https://dotnetfiddle.net/test?a=1", UriKind.Absolute, out var result6);
    Console.WriteLine(result6); // correct
}
```

I will get the following output:

```
https://dotnetfiddle.net/
https://dotnetfiddle.net:5555/
https://dotnetfiddle.net/?a=1
https://dotnetfiddle.net/
https://dotnetfiddle.net/?a=1
https://dotnetfiddle.net/test
https://dotnetfiddle.net/test?a=1
```

but I am looking for:

```
https://dotnetfiddle.net
https://dotnetfiddle.net:5555
https://dotnetfiddle.net?a=1
https://dotnetfiddle.net/
https://dotnetfiddle.net/?a=1
https://dotnetfiddle.net/test
https://dotnetfiddle.net/test?a=1
```

I read the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.trycreate?view=netframework-4.8) without finding about this issue.

How can I fix it to avoid the trailing '/' at the end of the uri? I would like to get the same output than my output. Keeping the `/` when I give one, but remove it when I dont.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Base Uri without a trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46968185/base-uri-without-a-trailing-slash)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little string builder with Uri segments

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            string url = "https://dotnetfiddle.net:333/?a=1";
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(url);
            Console.WriteLine(uri.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + uri.Host + (url.Contains(uri.Port.ToString()) ? ":" + uri.Port : "") + (uri.Path.Length > 1 ? uri.Path : uri.Path.TrimStart('/')) + uri.Query);
    }
}
```

Output : `https://dotnetfiddle.net:333?a=1`

Comment: I was looking for an answer in the form of an Uri (or alike) class and not a string. It is not possible. The slash is standard as shown in the question linked in comment. Thank you for taking the time to answer.